# apache cordova game development, is it valid?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I've been developing a game using libgdx (Java), it's basically a super mario game, a few moving objects, some sound effects, could something like that be done with html5 and javascript?

I tried searching the world wide web for some info, but didn't find a lot, I guess it's not common, or even possible?

I'm asking because I want to create non-game apps as well, and will be using apache cordova for those, would be nice to use the same language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, the best way to design a game with html5 and javascript is using the HTML5 Canvas, this supports everything you need : inputs, sounds. You will be able to make a platformer game with this.
It seems like canvas is supported by cordova. I've found something for you, it's about game development with PhoneGap, which is quite similar to Cordova, so i think it won't be too hard to do so with Cordova. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davrous/2011/12/23/tutorial-how-to-create-html5-applications-on-windows-phone-thanks-to-phonegap/

Comment: thx for that link, have not read through it yet, but seems good.

Comment: You should validate an answer if it seems correct to you, or be more specific in your question according to some users that already asked for more precision.